# if statements,lables and combo boxes

Tags: java, if-statement, jcombobox

Ok my code has to pick route combo box (check) display in label(check) have a return and single ticket combobox(check) need it to display text(check) my problem is it only prints text related to one of my statments hope someone can tell me how to fix my if statments. The lable changes on a button .It reads code by lable.So far it only prints 15 and wont print 20 unless i had another label but this wouldnt make sense for the program

```
    package learning;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList.*;
import java.util.Arrays.*;
import java.util.List.*;


@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class test {

    String[] items = {"Tipperary_to_cork","Cork_to_Dublin","Limerick_to_Tipperary","Dublin_to_Cork"};
    JComboBox c = new JComboBox(items);
    JButton b = new JButton("From");
    JLabel l = new JLabel();

    String[] items2 = {"window","aisle"};
    JComboBox m = new JComboBox(items2); 
    JButton  n = new JButton("Seat");
    JLabel  o = new JLabel();

    String[] items3 = {"Single","return"};
    JComboBox x = new JComboBox(items3); 
    JButton  y= new JButton("Ticket");
    JLabel  z = new JLabel("choose Ticket");

    String[] items4 = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"};
    JComboBox<?> xx = new JComboBox(items4); 
    JButton  yy = new JButton("seat");
    JLabel  zz = new JLabel("Choose a seat");
    JLabel  hh = new JLabel("cost");
    JButton  ccc = new JButton("comfirm");
    JLabel  hhh = new JLabel("");{

    }


    public test(){


    frame();

    }
     public void frame(){

    JFrame wolf = new JFrame();//frame
    wolf.setVisible(true);
    wolf.setSize(350,350);
    wolf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

    JPanel p = new JPanel();


    p.add(hh);
    p.add(c);//
    p.add(b);//
    p.add(l);//lable1
    p.add(m);//
    p.add(n);//
    p.add(o);//lable 2
    p.add(x);//
    p.add(y);//
    p.add(z);//lable 2
    p.add(xx);//
    p.add(yy);//
    p.add(zz);//lable 2
    p.add(ccc);
    p.add(hhh);
    wolf.add(p);


    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    String s = c.getSelectedItem().toString();
        l.setText(s);
        }
    });


     n.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String s = m.getSelectedItem().toString();
            o.setText(s);
            }
        });

     y.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String s = x.getSelectedItem().toString();
            z.setText(s);
            }
        });
     yy.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String s = xx.getSelectedItem().toString();
            zz.setText(s);
            }
        });
     }
     {

     if(l.getText().equals("Tipperary_to_cork")&&(z.getText().equals("single"))){
            ccc.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    hh.setText("15");                          //***

}});        
            if(l.getText().equals("Tipperary_to_cork")&&(z.getText().equals("return"))){
            ccc.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){      
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    hh.setText("20");                          //****

                }
            });     
            }}}
public static void main(String[]args){



    new test(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok ive dyslexia so when i type fast some times i type the wrong keys sorry  if my question is bad but i found it hard to phase. any advice on my code

Comment: `l.equals("Tipperary to cork")` will **always** return false. Because you are comparing `JLabel l` to a string (same with `JLabel  z`)

Comment: Well, what do you want to do? It appears you are trying to see if the text of the label is equal to `"Tipperary to cork"`, but it never is because you have `JLabel l = new JLabel("route");`

Comment: JLabel l = new JLabel("route"); i thought tis was just pre input text that be placed inside

Comment: It is. But you never change that to say `"Tipperary to cork"` anywhere in your code. At least not before the constructor of the class, where you compare it.

Comment: but there are other routes in my combox as well so how amy i ment to solve it.I can understand you point but i thought it was just the if statement at fault.so what code do i input or change.

Comment: You put the code in the constructor of your class. It is the first thing that is ran, and never again after that. I am working on an answer, but the short solution: Move the if statements to the ActionListeners for the buttons.

Comment: I highly advise you to use sensible variable names when coding, because it helps you (and others) to understand the flow of the code better. If you need a bunch of similar typed variables, you can use an Array/Vector.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check "if some condition" when you click the button. So, start with one simple if statement inside one of the `actionPerformed` methods. You shouldn't add an action listener inside an if statement, you should always perform an action, and determine the event inside that action.

For example

```
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String s = c.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if (s.equals("Tipperary to cork")) {
            // TODO: do something 
        }
    }
});
```

**Original answer**

These line just happen to work because you have `if(false==false)`

```
if(l.equals("Tipperary to cork")==(z.equals("single"))) { ... }
if(l.equals("Tipperary to cork")==(z.equals("return"))) { ... }
```

The reason they evaluate to `false` is because you are comparing a `JLabel.equals(String)`. You should use `l.getText().equals("text here")`, but...

The problem is that you have those if statements inside the constructor for your class, meaning that they are the first thing that is evaluated in your code. You should move the corrected if statements into the `ActionListener`s for the respective buttons.

Additional note: You seem to want `"Tipperary to cork"` AND `"single"`. In that case, use `&&` in place of `==`. Alternatively, you could do this (psuedocode intentional)

```
if "Tipperary to cork" {
    if "single" { ... }
    else if "return" { ... }
}
```

In reality, though, you should compare `c.getSelectedItem().toString()` instead of the text of the label, but that's your decision.

Comment: ok i changed my if statments but can u repeat    "You should move the corrected if statements into the ActionListeners for the respective buttons".    
ive lots of action listeners for the code the ones in the if statment the ones under the class that like 

wolf.add(p);

    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    String s = c.getSelectedItem().toString();
        l.setText(s);
        }
    });
ur helping me out alot I only need ur help puting these to in the right place and i can do the rest myself.

Comment: It may be useful to you to remove the buttons and [handle events on the combobox selection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#listeners)

Comment: i've swaped my if statements out side the class and the comfirm buttons click doesnt do anymore. 
 into the ActionListeners for the respective buttons" can u give me an example because im messing it up

Comment: You need to put the if statements inside the `actionPerformed`.  You are trying to do something when you click the button, not when you call the method. You don't add the action listener to the buttons inside the if statements